# what does the word STET mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

"There it lay,beside my plate, make-up with squiggles, circles and STETs --the arcana of the trade known mainly to professional editors."

I read this on the essay of The editors at the breakfast table written by Charles shields.

what is the meaning of STETs?

Comment: I found the essay online, and it is different https://brevitymag.com/craft-essays/the-editor-at-the-breakfast-table/   "**marked**-up with squiggles, circles, and **carets**"

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, you seem to be incorrectly quoting source material. The word *STET* is never actually used by that author in that article. Please provide accurate attribution. Otherwise, you are committing plagiarism.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this issue for me. It was one of homeworks from my translation course. I would like to explain that firstly it was a typing mistake of "marked-up" that I didn't realize and for the "STETs" I did exactly copied from my reading so I would email my teacher and talk about this. obviously I have never meant to commit plagiarism .

Answer (score 2):

"Stet" is Latin for "let it stand", and it means leave it in, the opposite of "dele", delete it. When it's pluralized as in your example, it means multiple instances of the word "stet" in the editing markup of a document.

[American Heritage Dictionary "stet"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stet)
"v.intr.
To direct that a letter, word, or other matter marked for omission or correction is to be retained. Used in the imperative.
v.tr.
To nullify (a correction or deletion) in printed matter."